# how can i recover my loss data?

Tags: data-loss

I have migrated from Windows 7 to Ubuntu just yesterday. Windows 7 was in my C: drive. I did not realise that if I wipe Windows 7 and install Ubuntu, Ubuntu would be installed in the C: drive only. So I didn't make any backups, and I deleted Windows and installed Ubuntu. But, Ubuntu has formatted my hard drive and I have lost all my important data!

How can I recover my data now?

Comment: If Ubuntu is installed onto your original Windows partition, I think data are gone. No recovery.

Answer (score 0):

I think if your still resides in HDD then, you can use puppy Linux to recover data.Its easy but will take time so you should be patient.
Now its time to Keep Calm and Install Puppy....  : )

here's the link for steps to follow --

[Recover Windows Data using Linux](https://www.winhelp.us/recover-files-using-puppy-linux.html)

But but if your drive is really formatted and data is wiped out then you should regret from mistakes and learn from them for future...